Google Sheets Import Range Appending Rows
I have been using the Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE() function to read in data from a master sheet booklet 1 to a different reference sheet booklet 2. I import columns A:E into booklet 2 from booklet 1 and then type in my own data in column F in booklet 2.
My issue is that as the master sheet changes (such as rows deleted, hidden, or moved), my typed column F data in sheet 2 is obviously not linked and no longer corresponds to the correct row of columns A:E.
Is there a way to import the data from the master sheet as text and append it as new rows are added? Or alternatively a way to link column F which is edited on booklet 2 to the rows of columns A:E from booklet 1?
Thanks for any help you can offer.
I have a feeling I may have to use Google scripts or perhaps there is a means to convert IMPORTRANGE() to plain text then append new data to it.

One way to do this is to "link" them together by means of a separate tab where you keep notes.  It is not easy to do if the data changes frequently, but there are ways around this.
Consider this as one possible option:
Imported data goes into Master Sheet.  On second sheet, show imported data with ARRAYFORMULA.  Then use Column H and Column I for keeping notes.  Use "Dropdown from a Range" validation in Column H to show all imported values.  This will remain static after a selection is made.  In Column I write the note associated with the chosen value.
Then, in Column F, use this formula to "bring back" the notes that you have kept:
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(A2:A,H2:H,I2:I,))

As values change in the imported range, the notes will stay in the correct row.
To help keep track, you can use conditional formatting to highlight values that do not have notes.  Apply conditional formatting to A2:A using this formula:
=countif(H$2:H, A2) = 0

